# login with pages and importig from pages

Tags: authentication, import, profile, facebook-page

i am currently working on an app, that requires people to use their facebook profile to sign in. My question is: is there any way for non-individuals to be able to sign in? I mean group pages, business pages etc, because i need to import their profile picture and their names. Maybe any other way/idea to import them.
That would really help my case.

Answer (score 0):

No. All Facebook accounts are supposed to belong to users. Users can be admins of groups and business pages, but there is no way to directly login to one of these without first logging in to their user account.

Businesses and groups sometimes incorrectly register themselves as users. There is no way to filter these out.

That said, if you make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/ID?fields=name,picture` where `ID` is from a user, group or business page, all of these return a name and profile picture.